# I am creating an AI Chatbot which repeatedly displays the error: Expected Bytes, descriptor found

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, deep-learning

The following code is the first few steps of building a chatbot using deep learning, I have tensorflow, cUDDN, CUDA installed but it still displays the same error. I have followed the video tutorials on youtube and downloaded all packages needed over two times just to be sure but it still doesnt get out of this specific error...

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
```

The error it displays is

```
expected bytes, Descriptor found
Stack trace:
 >  File "C:\Users\Himashi\source\repos\ChatBot\ChatBot\chatbot.py", line 6, in <module>
 >    import tflearn
Loaded 'tensorflow.core.framework.resource_handle_pb2'
Loaded 'tensorflow.core.framework.tensor_pb2'
Loaded 'tensorflow.core.framework.attr_value_pb2'
Loaded 'tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2'
Loaded 'tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2'
Loaded 'tensorflow.python'
Loaded 'tensorflow'
Loaded 'tflearn.config'
Loaded 'tflearn'
Loaded '__main__'
Loaded 'runpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 39, in debug
    run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\source\repos\ChatBot\ChatBot\chatbot.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\node_def_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Himashi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\resource_handle_pb2.py", line 92, in <module>
    __module__ = 'tensorflow.core.framework.resource_handle_pb2'
TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment (conda/venv)?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be TensorFlow installation issue.

Also, your code only reads a JSON file. If that's only what you want, you could remove import of `tflearn` & `tensorflow` packages.

If you want to use these packages later, then I would suggest checking your TensorFlow installation (follow this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35208) for solution) or update TensorFlow.